# Number of possible strings for a given string

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm quite confused on how to calculate the number of all the possible strings that can occur for a given string.
For example take the word 'cat', such that we can generate the possibilities:

'cat', 'cta', 'atc', 'act', 'tac', 'tca', 'at', 'ac', 'ct', 'ca', 'ta', 'tc', 'a', 'c', 't'.

Is there any mathematical formula to calculate the above? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No simple formula is known. But if all the letters are different, it's not hard to calculate. Let's write $a(n)$ for the number of possible strings you can make from a string with $n$ letters, all different. For example, you observed that $a(3)=15$ because "cat" has 3 letters and 15 strings can be made from it.

Then: $$a(n) = n\cdot a(n-1) +n.$$

This means you can calculate $a(4)$ as $4\cdot15+4=64$ and $a(5)$ as $5\cdot 64+5=325$.

If not all the letters are different, the problem is more complicated. For example, only 8 strings, not 15, can be made from `poo`.

More advanced information is available at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A007526).

I hope this is helpful.

---

Addendum: A simple formula *is* known, and it is amazing.  According to OEIS, $$a(n) = \left\lfloor e\cdot n! - 1\right\rfloor,$$

where [$e=2.71828…$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) and $\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$ means to throw away the fraction part.

Comment: The appearance of the $n!$ isn't surprising, since the basic recursion is $a(n) = n\cdot a(n-1)$.  But I find it remarkable that the fudge factor is exactly $e$.